# Difference between I and Me

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I am quite confused with the usage of I and me, Can anybody tell me what should be used in the following sentence: Your husband doesn't believe that You're older than (I / Me).

Comment: "Your husband doesn't believe that you're older than *me*".

Comment: I too thought that me should be used but it's I not me. It was a grammar check problem from Norman Lewis book.

Comment: @Karasinsky I think its him only but I mentioned in above comment, in the sentence I provided 'I' was used as object but no idea why?

Comment: Older and more prescriptive (and less true to the way English is actually used) grammars will insist on 'he' here. Anyone answering that way on ELU will almost certainly be downvoted. The nearest thing English has to a Czar, Geoff Pullum, would tell you to ignore people telling you that you must use (or even using) 'he' here.

Comment: yes, I got it now but still there is confusion when to consider than as conjunction and when as preposition. which is more acceptable?

Comment: @vingo, I think you'll find a decent explanation in the duplicate post linked to. On your very specific point above, remember that "object" is a grammatical term. Asking why an objective pronoun is used is a fancy way of asking "why do we say 'me' in sentences like this?' and with this in mind I think you'll find the linked-to discussion more helpful than you might be imagining.